# Idiom request for "the reverse is also true"

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

***Vice versa*** is a idiomatic, concise way of expressing that the `converse` (other way around) of the preceding statement is also true. E.g:

> Matter that has lowest boiling point will boil first, and ***vice versa*** (matter that boils first will have the lowest boiling point)

I would like to know if there are also  idioms/short expressions for stating that the `reverse` (opposite of the entire preceding statement) also holds true. i.e:

> Matter that has lowest boiling point will boil first, and ....... (matter with the highest boiling point will boil last)

What can I put in ....... ?

Comment: Matter that has the lowest (respectively highest) boiling point will boil first (resp. last)

Comment: **conversely** is the word you want, as I have suggested in my answer below; and by the way I am not sure 'vice versa' can be used in the way you have used it in the above example. *Vice versa* indicates reciprocity and *converse* indicates reversal. An example for a typical use of 'vice versa' would be *'he was her nominee and vice versa'* (he nominated her, presumably for some insurance policy, and *she nominated him* = vice versa.) Please check online for the scope of 'vice versa' and its range of accepted usage.

Comment: If matter with the lowest boiling point boils first, then it follows that matter with the highest boiling point boils last. There is no reverse of ideas in there. Either you need a different example sentence or you don't actually want the "reverse". I personally find that "vice versa" works perfectly fine for saying the low=boil first, high=boil last.

Comment: "you can turn that around", "it works the other way too"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Conversely**

> conversely (ADVERB)
>   Introducing a statement or idea which *reverses* one that has just been made or referred to.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/conversely

To *reverse* your sentence, 'lowest boiling point' must be reversed to 'highest boiling point' and 'will boil first' becomes 'will boil last.' (of course you have provided this  reversal yourself)

> Matter that has lowest boiling point will boil first; ***conversely,*** matter with the highest boiling point will boil last.

Comment: If matter with the lowest boiling point boils first, then it follows that matter with the highest boiling point boils last. There is no reverse of ideas in there. Conversely could be used in sentences such as: "In English the adjective goes before the noun, **conversely** in French it goes after the noun." However, this is a problem with the question, not your answer.

Comment: @Andy T you are right about the 'other' use of the word to mean 'opposite' or 'on the other hand'; but 'conversely' in scientific statements like the above **reverses the statement** (the physical / chemical / mathematical conditions stated) and is not intended to be a 'reversal of ideas.' AND PLEASE NOTE that *if matter with the lowest boiling point boils first "it follows" that matter with the highest boiling point boils last,* **only if** the statement / principle / law uses the word ***'conversely'!*** In other words, we cannot assume that the converse is true **unless stated explicitly.**

Answer (score 1):

**analogously**, according to [Oxford Dictionary Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/analogous) analogous means

> Comparable in certain respects, typically in a way which makes clearer the nature of the things compared.

One of their sample sentences for analogously:

> ‘This is more or less correct (given the obvious uncertainties in long term data from the continental interior), but **analogously** to the example above, local cooling does not contradict global warming.’

In your sentence:

> Matter that has the lowest boiling point will boil first, and analogously matter with the highest boiling point will boil last.

Attribution:

"Analogous | Definition of Analogous in English by Oxford Dictionaries." Oxford Dictionaries | English. Accessed May 25, 2018. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/analogous.

"Analogously | Definition of Analogously in English by Oxford Dictionaries." Oxford Dictionaries | English. Accessed May 25, 2018. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/analogously.

Answer (score 0):

Antonymically adjective. Diametrically opposed: antipodal, antipodean, antithetical, antonymous, contradictory, contrary, converse, counter, diametric, diametrical, opposing, opposite, polar, reverse. The American Heritage® Roget's Thesaurus.

Yes there is a case for some new words in the language instead of floundering around racking your brains and looking for THE word on google into the small hours! It took me 3 days to find a particular word and then it was so unknown it was useless really.